# Windows Phone 8.1 File Picker UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, filepicker

I have a problem trying to replicate the File Picker example in [link](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/File-picker-sample-9f294cba), I create a new application using a Universal Application Windows store template.

I extract the content of the class `Scenario02` and create a similar one in my example. This class implements an interface called `IFileOpenPickerContinuable` which I extract from the class `ContinuationManager` and create a file in my project with the same name to implement that interface.

I don't get any compilation errors when I run the application. When the line `openPicker.PickMultipleFilesAndContinue();` is executed, it throw a exception.

> 'UnauthorizedAccessException'(Access is denied. Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005) exception.

In the Microsoft example they don't modify any of the manifests of the application. Do you know what can I be missing?

Comment: What thread do you call it from? Also is there any additional information in the Output Window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

([Question solved in a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que))

The OP wrote:

> **Solved! The problem was trying to launch the data picker in the class constructor.**